# Using a variable to refer to a div id?

Tags: jquery, html, for-loop

I'm trying unsuccessfully to use a variable to cycle through a whole bunch of sequential div ids. I can't seem to figure out how refer to the ids as it goes through the loop.

```
var round1matchups = 32;

for (i=1;i<round1matchups;i++) {
    var currentmatch = "r1m"+i;
    $('"#'+currentmatch+' .team1"').html("json data here");
};
```

Comment: Consider using classes instead a sequence of ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've put an extraneous `"` in front of the id:

```
$('#'+currentmatch+' .team1').html("json data here");
// ^----- no " here        ^----- no " here
```

Comment: still an extra one at end `$('#'+currentmatch+' .team1')` ;)

Comment: @Layne: Thanks for the edit! I was a way for bit. (I can't imagine what those two users who "rejected" the edit were thinking; fortunately three others were on the ball.) Thanks also A. Wolff for pointing out the oversight.

Answer (score 2):

Loose the double quotes. The code should look like this:

```
$('#'+currentmatch+' .team1').html("json data here");
```